# How can i get my Preferences in a other class than the main (Android)?

Tags: android, button, preferences, adapter

My main class look like this:

```
public class Soundboard extends Activity 
{ 
    SharedPreferences preferences;

 @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 


     // Initialize preferences
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

}

private void loadButtonText() {
        startPlayerBtn.setText(preferences.getString("buttontext1", "n/a"));

}
```

This i workning but I have change my code a litte bit with a [ButtonAdapter](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/) (extra class) but cant find my Preferences there. I you look att the link I have an array that look like this in ButtonAdapter.java:

```
 public String[] filesnames = {
             "Text button 1",
            "Text button 2",  
            "Text button 3"
            };
```

How can I but my settings into the array? Something like this that is not working:

```
     public String[] filesnames = {
            preferences.getString("buttontext1", "n/a",
            preferences.getString("buttontext2", "n/a",  
            preferences.getString("buttontext3", "n/a"
            };
```

Please help me, I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor to look like this:

```
public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {  
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    filenames = new String[] {
        preferences.getString("buttontext1", "n/a"),
        preferences.getString("buttontext2", "n/a")
    }
}
```

And then change how you're declaring the filenames array at the end of the class to look like this:

```
public String[] filenames;
```

Answer (score 0):

What `getDefaultSharedPreferences` is waiting for is a `Context` object. So, the easy way to do it in your case, if you followed the tutorial is:

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
```